# GDB: Ctrl+C doesn't interrupt process as it usually does but rather terminates the program

Tags: gdb, signals

Normally when you run a program through GDB you can press Ctrl+C to interrupt it, e.g. if it gets stuck in an infinite loop and you want to get a backtrace.

I'm debugging a program (xmms2d as it happens) but in this program only, when I press Ctrl+C it gets treated as if GDB was not running - the program shuts down cleanly and then GDB tells me the program exited normally.

How do I get the usual GDB behaviour back, where Ctrl+C interrupts the program?  Or is there another way to produce the same reaction in GDB as a Ctrl+C normally does?

Comment: What is your GDB version and OS? Can you produce a minimal C program where it also happens?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: This problem was solved four years ago (see below) - a sample program probably isn't that relevant anymore!

Comment: 1000+ people come here every year looking for answers :-) New questions can be closed as duplicates of this one. But I don't blame you if you forgot the details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'll bet that xmms2d is using sigwait() to handle signals, which breaks gdb's ability to catch CTRL-C. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9039

I got an idea for a workaround by reading [Continue to debug after failed assertion on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721543/) -- when I'm ready to break in gdb, I run "kill -TRAP <pid>" from another terminal window.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to unblock gdb like that when the underlying process hangs. Both gdb and my process still hang :-( Any other hints?

Comment: for others wondering '<pid>' refers to the inferior process here (not gdb)

Answer (score 10):

In the gdb prompt you can do "handle SIGINT stop" so that gdb catches CTRL-C

Comment: This doesn't work if the debugged process is invoking [`sigwait()`](https://manpath.be/c7/3/sigwait). And `handle SIGINIT stop` should be set, by default.

Comment: I have no reason to even doubt the wisdom of @maxschlepzig... and yet sunil's answer helped me to realize that `handle SIGINT pass` was the solution to the (~opposite) problem that Google brought me here with.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem caused by SDL signal handlers that interfere with gdb.
One solution I find to workaround this when starting gdb:

```
start
call sigignore(2)
continue
```

Now all CTRL-C will be ignored by application.

If you `attach` to some process and want to restore it to original condition after debuging, you can do this:

```
set $oldcallback = signal(2, 0)
call sigignore(2)
continue
```

And when you are done:

```
call signal(2, $oldcallback)
detach
```

Comment: I guess that causes the application to ignore the signal, but gdb still doesn't stop for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that running GDB under `rlwrap` breaks its ability to intercept `^C` correctly. If you are doing this, then try running it without `rlwrap`.

Comment: If you are right, it is a bug. I cannot reproduce it - can you give an example or, better still, [file a bug report](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)? BTW: `gdb` uses `readline`, so why use `rlwrap` at all?

Comment: @HansLub I was annoyed that GDB didn't remember my command history between sessions, hence my usage of `rlwrap`. I'm afraid I don't have the time to generate a bug report at present, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I have **solved** it.

First, write a `gdb` script, the file name is `sighhandler.gdb`. The script file is in the project directory:

```
gdb_sigwait/src/sighandler.gdb
```

Then, `source` the above script file in the `gdb` initialization file (`~/.gdbinit`), for example:

```
source ~/gdb_sigwait/src/sighandler.gdb
```

The `gdb` script is too long.
So, I created a github project to introduce and store the related code:
https://github.com/fairyfar/gdb_sigwait

Comment: Hi FairyFar. Welcome to the stack! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, and links should be for supplementing/clarifying content. Please update your answer so that the solution is included in the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can change GDB's input/output target using the following command:

```
gdb -tty = /dev/tty1
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  The output does go to the other terminal, but when you press Ctrl+C on gdb's terminal, the program being debugged still catches the signal and exits cleanly, just as if you hadn't changed the tty at all.